# DRF 3.7.0 removed handling None in fields and broke my foreign key source fields. Is there a way around it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I noticed that [this Django Rest Framework commit](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/commit/07258ca032e062334310c112469d6432f6eeb818) broke my project when upgrading from `3.6.3` to `3.7.0`. Here's the relevant part of the model that is now broken:

```
class MarketingPlan(models.Model):
    promotion = models.ForeignKey(Promotion, null=True)

class MarketingPlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    promotion = serializers.CharField(
        source='fk_promotion.id',
        read_only=False,
        allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MarketingPlan
        fields = ('promotion',)
```

Accessing the `data` attribute of this serializer, when the `Promotion` foreign key is `None`

```
>> mp = MarketingPlan.objects.first()
>> MarketingPlanSerializer(mp).data

rest_framework/fields.py", line 100, in get_attribute
instance = getattr(instance, attr)
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

So whereas `get_attribute` used to skip `None`, now it goes searching for the `.id` attribute of the related field `promotion` in my particular case, even when it's `None`.

What's the workaround for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you need to explicitly set a default value to the serializer's related field:

```
class MarketingPlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    promotion = serializers.CharField(
        source='fk_promotion.id',
        read_only=False,
        allow_null=True,
        default=None)
    class Meta:
        model = MarketingPlan
        fields = ('promotion',)
```

Comment: Thanks! My google-fu is broken - where's that documented?

Comment: imho, documentation on that topic could be improved but I'm lacking time to deal with it.

Comment: Hm, I've tried it out and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: release note have some mention about the use of `source` and default but not explicitly stated. I'll be happy if someone can come with a PR to improve that.

Comment: [here's the source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/07258ca032e062334310c112469d6432f6eeb818/rest_framework/fields.py) - at line 96 onwards there doesn't seem to be any logic that checks for default values. Where is the `default` kwarg processed?

Comment: This looks like what I mentioned in https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5489 but I managed to fix my attribute errors by using default=None. I don't think I've given the 3.7.1 a try though - might have changed.

Comment: I've now tried for 3.7.0 and 3.7.1 and the error is there for both. Looks like a proper bug. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hm. A `default=None` should work here. Are you sure it's not because your `source` is `fk_promotion.id` instead of `promotion.id`?

Comment: My bad, it was because I use a different child serializer class for the bulk operations, and I forgot to change both classes. This issue is subject to a patch on the next release anyway as per https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5518.

Answer (score 0):

...if you happen to come across this like i did, it's in the docs now at

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

e.g.  "When serializing fields with dotted notation, it may be necessary to provide a default value if any object is not present or is empty during attribute traversal."  ([commit](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5489/commits/9f21095a1116ff8eff656358fc66142614b88c9a))